# Importance of Reverse Proxy using ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, reverse-proxy, needle.js

Good day everyone,
Today, i came across a pop-up post about proxies and reverse-proxies using expressJS and needle. I've never thought of using it before and i'm curious. My questions are;
When should a developer/company use proxies, why should they use it, how important is it, what modules can the "proxy" be implemented using Nodejs and Expressjs, what are the best practices for using proxies?
Thanks for reviewing my question. Links to a video tutorial or resource will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why/When use Proxy =>

- To control internet usage of employees and minors
- Bandwidth savings and improved speeds
- Privacy benefits
- Improved security
- Get access to blocked resources

Other information in the [link 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGymN8aFsv4&t=35s), [link 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nCWE6eonL7k)  .I hope You will be content;-)